# What is the simplest way to create a vertically scrolling div in the Android Browser?

Tags: css, html, scroll, android-browser

**Note:** I realize very similar questions have been asked, but the mobile web is young and volatile, and those discussions being a couple of years old are likely out of date.

I'm trying to create a simple scrolling `<div>` in the Android browser- what would be a accomplished by giving it a fixed size and `overflow-y: auto` in a compliant browser. Unfortunately, mobile Webkit browsers don't seem to support that attribute. How else can I create this functionality or something equivalent?

I'd prefer a CSS solution if possible. I've seen the JavaScript widgets [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) and [Dojo Mobile lists](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/mobile.html#lists) but those seem like overkill for what I'm trying to do. The iScroll page mentions that "latest Android revisions are supporting this functionality (although support is not optimal)" so I wonder if Android 4.0 might have fixed this problem.

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with just pure css, you need a javascript widget to handle it

Answer (score 1):

I've used the standard touch events to good effect across a lot of different devices. If it's only a simple solution, rather than a weighty plugin just use the `touchstart` `touchmove` and `touchend` events top calculate movement and modify the scrollTop.

I couldn't find a standard CSS way across devices, but maybe webkit has some proprietary stuff.

P.S this was in the last 3 months.

**[update]**

You can use these events like any other,

```
var startX = 0;
var startY = 0;
var ele = document.getElementById('myScrollableDiv');
ele.addEventListener('touchstart', function(ev){
    startX = ev.screenX;
    startY = ev.screenY;
});

ele.document.getElementById('myScrollableDiv').addEventListener('touchmove', function(ev){
    movementX = startX - ev.screenX;
    movementY = startY - ev.screenY;
    ele.style.scrollLeft = ele.style.scrollLeft + movementX;
    ele.style.scrollTop = ele.style.scrollTop + movementY;
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

This is completely from memory so it'll need some testing I can't do at the minute, and I don't have the code I used at the minute either (though that was in jQuery). This method does work nicely eventually, there's just a few things to work out. Hopefully that's enough of the gist for you to work off.

Comment: I'm not familiar with those event types. Could you include a quick example?